# Get data from MQ and add id number for it

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am new to java. I need to receive data from MQ, each time I receive data I give it a id number, like 1, 2, 3.....  My Question is when I restart this program, how can I make the id number keep adding, not start from 1. For example,  now I received 3 data from MQ, IDs are 1, 2 and 3, then I close my program. Next time I run my program and recieve data, I want the id number start from 4, not 1. 
I know it can be done by record the id number into a text file, but I worry about the safety, because every one can change it. is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English

Comment: Is this the IBM MQ product you refer to as MQ?  If so every MQ messages has a MessageID associated with it.  In most cases the sending application lets the IBM MQ Queue Manager generate the MessageID and as such it is a unique ID assuming normal setup, no duplicate queue manager names and the clock do not go backwards in time.  Instead of generating your own ID number just use the IBM MQ MessageID.

Comment: It is IBM MQ, and Thank you. I will try it